# How to drop clustered property but retain primary key in a table. SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, primary-key, clustered-index

i have the following key:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.Table ADD  CONSTRAINT PK_ID PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
ID ASC
)
```

so i have clustered index and primary key on ID column.
Now i need to drop clustered index (i want to create new clustered index on another column), but retain primary key.
Is it possible?

Comment: I agree with @Demas but what edition of SQL Server are you on? (e.g. Enterprise/Standard). Do you have to worry about concurrent users? Do you have other non clustered indexes on the table?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It's not possible in one statement, but because DDL is transactional in MSSQL, you can simply do everything inside a transaction to prevent other sessions accessing the table while it has no primary key:

```
begin tran
alter table dbo.[Table] drop constraint pk_id
alter table dbo.[Table] add constraint pk_id primary key nonclustered (id)
commit tran
```

Answer (score 3):

It is not possible, as the index is a physical implementation of the constraint.